# What to include in configuration of tslint.json?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I don't know which rule should be included in `tslint.json`. Can anyone show me the common or standard use of `tslint.json`?

How to write a tslint.json file?

Comment: configuring it depends on what you want to achieve. you can generate a default one using tsc --init

Comment: @toskv You probably mean `tslint --init`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> how to write a tslint.json file

The Docs: https://palantir.github.io/tslint

Here is an example `tslint.json`: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/

You would only use the rules that you care about: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/

E.g. a small sample:

```
{
    "rules": {
        "no-unreachable": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure of the quality of the sample configuration functionally. You could also try https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/tslint.json or https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/tslint.json. Note that TypeScript uses some custom rules, so you'll need to grab those from their repo as well or just delete them from the config.

Comment: `Here is an example straight from the docs : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/docs/sample.tslint.json` -> link is dead :/

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but this might help others so just thought of posting the comment. tslint.json gives us better configuration for clean code and multiple custom options like using custom quotes, custom indentation etc. My tslint with Angular 8 looks like this which you can use as a reference if:

```
{
  "rulesDirectory": [
  "node_modules/codelyzer"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [true],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      "static-before-instance",
      "variables-before-functions"
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      "always"
   ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "typeof-compare": true,
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ],

    "directive-selector": [true, "attribute", "app", "camelCase"],
    "component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"],
    "use-input-property-decorator": true,
    "use-output-property-decorator": true,
    "use-host-property-decorator": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "use-life-cycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "no-access-missing-member": true,
    "templates-use-public": true,
    "invoke-injectable": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I based on the former reply and updated to a working `tslint.config`:

```json
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "callable-types": true,
    "class-name": true,
    "comment-format": [
      true,
      "check-space"
    ],
    "curly": true,
    "eofline": true,
    "forin": true,
    "import-blacklist": [
      true
    ],
    "import-spacing": true,
    "indent": [
      true,
      "spaces"
    ],
    "interface-over-type-literal": true,
    "label-position": true,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": "fields-first"
      }
    ],
    "no-arg": true,
    "no-bitwise": true,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-construct": true,
    "no-debugger": true,
    "no-duplicate-variable": true,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-empty-interface": true,
    "no-eval": true,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-shadowed-variable": true,
    "no-string-literal": false,
    "no-string-throw": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": true,
    "no-unused-expression": true,
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "one-line": [
      true,
      "check-open-brace",
      "check-catch",
      "check-else",
      "check-whitespace"
    ],
    "prefer-const": true,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "radix": true,
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-null-check"
    ],
    "typedef-whitespace": [
      true,
      {
        "call-signature": "nospace",
        "index-signature": "nospace",
        "parameter": "nospace",
        "property-declaration": "nospace",
        "variable-declaration": "nospace"
      }
    ],
    "unified-signatures": true,
    "variable-name": false,
    "whitespace": [
      true,
      "check-branch",
      "check-decl",
      "check-operator",
      "check-separator",
      "check-type"
    ]
  },
  "jsRules": {
    "max-line-length": {
      "options": [
        120
      ]
    }
  }
}
```